# Smoothing artifacts & other problems?

Tags: modeling, smooth

I'm trying to make a smooth edge to a cylinder, but there's some weird artifacting that I guess can be solved with more polygons, but I'm trying to keep the poly-count to a minimum. Additionally on the cone at the top, the faces aren't shaded smooth how they should, it technically is shaded smooth but you can clearly make out every edge.

[image]

Here's the model.

[image]

Here's the wireframe of the model.

Comment: Have you got autosmooth turned on?

Comment: Yes. Should it be off?

Comment: No, especially if you are using the weighted normal modifier. If you haven't, it might help to look at what the manual says about the modifier and its settings at: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/weighted_normal.html  You might try changing the autosmooth angle and see if that helps. Also, you would probably have a much better chance of getting an answer if you were to attach your .blend file to your question at: https://blend-exchange.com/ Then someone who knows about topology issues might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem you're highlighting in the bottom part? It seems like it's smooth as you want, no? As Curious says, could you please share your file?